# Meteor.user() is undefined in client-side controller

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

In the client-side of a METEORJS application, i have a controller that display some users.

I have a problem with Meteor.user() function, the error is : Meteor.user(...) is undefined.

Here is my code :

```
this.AdminUsersController = RouteController.extend({
template: "Admin",


yieldTemplates: {
    'AdminUsers': { to: 'AdminSubcontent'}

},

onBeforeAction: function() {
    var permissions = Meteor.user().profile.permissions;
    if (permissions && permissions.indexOf('Users') != -1)
        this.next();
    else this.redirect('/admin/dashboard');
},

action: function() {
    if(this.isReady()) { this.render(); } else { this.render("Admin"); this.render("loading", { to: "AdminSubcontent" });}
    /*ACTION_FUNCTION*/
},

isReady: function() {


    var subs = [
        Meteor.subscribe("users")
    ];
    var ready = true;
    _.each(subs, function(sub) {
        if(!sub.ready())
            ready = false;
    });
    return ready;
},

data: function() {

    var data = {
        params: this.params || {},
        users: Users.find({labo_id: Meteor.user().profile.labo_id}, {sort: {createdAt:-1}})
    };


    return data;
},

onAfterAction: function() {

}});
```

It's in the data function.
I try to retrieve all users that are connected to the logged in user and got the same labo_id field...

I don't know why it give me that, because in the onBeforeAction function, i can access to Meteor.user(), and specially his profile...

Someone know what can i do to make it run ?

Thanks for your future answers :)

Comment: I suppose the logical answer is that no user is logged in when the data() function is called.

Comment: The user is logged in, the adminusercontroller render and manage a private part of the application, so the user has to be logged to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a timing issue. Meteor.user() does not necessarily return data, if it hasn't been loaded yet. Meteor.userId() however will return the _id of the user record (if they are logged in). If you can change your query to rely on that _id, then it can work.

Depending on which router you are using, you can add a resolve: entry to ensure that the route waits for the user record to be loaded before activating it, and then your query will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !

Yeah i'm using the iron router, i think too it's a timing issue.

I try what you said and come back later to you, thanks.

Comment: I solved it, just add if(Meteor.user()) { ... } around the query to retrieve users.
Now it's working, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the error was ***Meteor.user() is not a function***

In my case, I needed to install the Meteor package accounts-password by doing

`meteor add accounts-password`